# Getting Information about a assembly which is present in Solution

Tags: reflection, assembly-loading

Scenario: I want to load a assembly at run time which is present in Solution.

The belo code will not work as it is not present in Cuurent App Domain.

```
Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
```

Also if i will search in referenced assemblies, then also it can not be found as it is not referenced. So the below code will also not work:

```
public static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        var stack = new Stack<Assembly>();

        stack.Push(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

        do
        {
            var asm = stack.Pop();

            yield return asm;

            foreach (var reference in asm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                if (!list.Contains(reference.FullName))
                {
                    stack.Push(Assembly.Load(reference));
                    list.Add(reference.FullName);
                }

        }
        while (stack.Count > 0);

    }
```

Do you guyz have some suggestion ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to dynamically load an assembly? If so, the assembly won't be present in the AppDomain. You can use Assembly.Load() to load a DLL file from disk.

Comment: Assembly.Load() will require a path, and i don't want to hard code anything in my code. Can you show me how can i achieve this without specifying the path ?

Comment: If you don't specify a path, it won't know where the file is located. Without hardcoding, you could put the location in the App.config file, so the DLLs location is fluid.

Comment: But in App.Config also I need to input the hard code path, and I think this will not work in others machine. Please correct me if I am wrong here ?

Comment: Maybe you could clarify exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

[Sign your assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247123%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then in your app.config, specify the [fully qualified assembly name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8xx4k69.aspx).  Call [Assembly.Load(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx), passing the assembly name from your app.config.

NOTE: The assembly you are attempting to load must be in a location where the runtime can find it.  Your best bet is either to put it into the [Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or make sure it is in the same folder as your executing assembly.