# Cannot cast to seemingly same class

Tags: c#, casting, .net-5

I am writing C# in .NET-5 and trying to instantiate a class based on some XML. This seem to work fine as I get an instance of the desired object:

```
var refxmlFileInfo = new FileInfo(settings.COBDateSetting);
// Casting fails. The Object is of the expected type
CalcConfiguration.CobDateSettings = (COBDate_Settings)factoryHelper.GetInstance(refxmlFileInfo, xmlFileInfo.FullName);
```

However, the casting fails with a strange error which indicates that the instance and the target are of the same type:

```
[A]DataModel.BusinessDays.COBDate_Settings cannot be cast to
[B]DataModel.BusinessDays.COBDate_Settings.

Type A originates from 'DataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
'<REMOVED>\bin\Debug\net5.0\DataModel.dll'.

Type B originates from 'DataModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
'<REMOVED>\bin\Debug\net5.0\DataModel.dll'.
```

I have checked the references between the projects but could not spot any anomalies.

```
public object GetInstance(FileInfo xmlFileInfo,string usedWhere)
{
   ISettings setting = GetSettings(xmlFileInfo, usedWhere);
   var classToResolve = ((IDefiningType)setting).GetDefiningType();
   var classInstance = (IInitializeXML)Unity.Resolve(classToResolve);
   classInstance.InitializeXML(this, xmlFileInfo);
   return classInstance;
}

public ISettings GetSettings(FileInfo xmlFileInfo,string usedWhere)
{
   if (!xmlFileInfo.Exists)
   {
     var msg = string.Format("Path: <{0}> not found in referenced file: {1}", xmlFileInfo.FullName,usedWhere);
     throw new Exception(msg);
    }

// Uses some regex to find out which class is XML-Serialized. The string is // then checked against all types in assembly. Types are extracted using
// *.dll and the loading the assembly
var typeToResolve = GetSettingsType(xmlFileInfo);
// We now have a instance of the definingType class
ISettings setting = (ISettings)Convert.ChangeType(SettingsSerializer.Deserialize(typeToResolve, xmlFileInfo), typeToResolve);
            return setting;
 }
```

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: Different assembly load contexts perhaps? What is `factoryHelper`? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: In the error message one can see, that the DLLs are both in the "default" context.

Comment: Might there be an issue with my way of looking in the assemblies via: var dir = new DirectoryInfo(baseDir);
            foreach (var dllfile in dir.GetFiles("*.dll"))
            {var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllfile.FullName);

Comment: Again, a [mcve] is really the way to make it easier for us to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The reason was that I iterated over the DLLs using the LoadFile:

```
var baseDir = AppContext.BaseDirectory;
var dir = new DirectoryInfo(baseDir);
foreach (var dllfile in dir.GetFiles("*.dll"))
```

It seems as if C# does not recognize that the classes are the same and that they are coming from the same dll. I fixed the problem by using a solution from this post:

[Getting Information about a assembly which is present in Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12837301/getting-information-about-a-assembly-which-is-present-in-solution)

```
public IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
        {
            var list = new List<string>();
            var stack = new Stack<Assembly>();

            stack.Push(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());

            do
            {
                var asm = stack.Pop();

                yield return asm;

                foreach (var reference in asm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                    if (!list.Contains(reference.FullName))
                    {
                        stack.Push(Assembly.Load(reference));
                        list.Add(reference.FullName);
                    }

            }
            while (stack.Count > 0);

        }
```

However in this case I had to reference all assemblies AND also call something within the referenced assemblies. The code above seems to work only if the dlls have already be loaded.